# can I rely on the browser logic against an incomplete web page?

Tags: android, html, browser, android-webview

I have testes the following code in Google Chrome to simulate a connection interrupt while loading a web page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
</head>

<body>
<script>
var a=1;
```

when I inspect the rendered web page , the incomplete  tag is completed automatically by Chrome and I have the following rendered source and this is OK for my project:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
</head>

<body>
<script>
var a=1;
</script></body></html>
```

I am afraid if all browsers (specially **android webView**) treat same against an incomplete web page? Is this a general behavior or general **HTML 5** rule about incomplete codes or this is the special behavior of Google Chrome?

> *Why this is important for me?*
>   *The most number of my application users are international drivers and they experience connection interruption or slow connections while using the app. So I want
>   to write my code in a way that if they loose the connection, the
>   remaining part of web page looks good.*

Comment: Idk FF works the same way. Btw why would you want to write your HTML file like that?

Comment: I have added a description about why this is important for me @BrianLe

Comment: I believe that no matter how slow the connect is, the full HTML markup will be rendered. You might want to look into service worker, or resources optimisation for slow connection

Comment: The HTML5 parsing rules are tightly defined, and *should* work exactly the same way in all browsers. Of course there is always a risk that a particular browser is not compliant with those rules.